# Inheritance from children to parents?

Tags: object-oriented-design, interfaces, inheritance, abstract-class

Seeing this UML class diagram :

[image]

FileHandler, Uploader and Deleter are abstract classes.
The four bottom classes are implementations. They extend on FileHandlerInterface which requires a handle method to validate the contract.
But this method isn't in the implementations, it is in their parents (Uploader & Deleter).

I did this because I didn't like the idea of implementing an interface in an abstract class.

Although, I feel like there's a huge flaw in this design. The fact that it is needed to go through parents to know how the child works makes me feel like it's bad design.

To be more precise, it is unclear that UploaderComplete's direct parent has a method "handle" even thought it needs it. It could be in Uploader's parent (and recursively).

Where is this design wrong and how could I improve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: *“I didn't like the idea of implementing an interface in an abstract class”*: why?

Comment: i would have the abstract classes implement the interface. but i don't think your design is 'bad'

Comment: What does `handle` actually do?

Comment: @MainMa Because to me it's not explicit that children will be the one defining the interface implementation which is kind of sad since it should help understanding what this class is and does, isn't it ?

Comment: @BenAaronson this is where it gets fuzzy. Handle will call $this->upload() after using a Validator and a directory generator. $this->upload that is to be defined in children.

Comment: Is the `Deleter` implementation of `handle` different to the `Uploader`'s? (Other than calling `delete()` rather than `upload()`)

Comment: @BenAaronson Both will use their own validator to validate the file and the path and both will use the implementation that they require in an abstract method (upload for Uploader, delete for Deleter). Only Uploader will generate directories.

Comment: It's very unclear what are you trying to do: DeleterChunks will use the handle() of its mother-class or the handle() of the FileHandleInterface? Are they the same? If yes why don't just add an handle() function in the FileHandle class?

Comment: @JoulinRouge The FileHandlerInterface only defines a contract with handle(). Handle() doesn't have a body in the interface. So only handle() in the mother-class of DeleterChunks will be called indeed !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FileHandler` should implement `FileHandlerInterface`. Abstract methods common to all children such as `handle()` should be hoisted to `FileHandlerInterface` if public, `FileHandler` if not.

The purpose of abstract classes and interfaces is to define the contract for concrete classes and allow polymorphism. If I am handed `FileHandlerInterface` I should be able to do whatever I need regardless of the actual implementation.

Based on the diagram in the question, it looks like polymorphism will work as expected if you are passing around `FileHandlerInterface` references.

However, your hierarchy is *brittle*. If you make a change in one part of the hierarchy, it may cause inconsistencies with other parts of the hierarchy. Furthermore, it is possible to define another subclass of `FileHandler` but you might forget to add `FileHandlerInterface`. The fact that it is possible to create a new file handler that is not effectively a file handler tells me that hierarchy is incorrect and `FileHandler` must implement `FileHandlerInterface`.